# How do I show that u solves the homogenous equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: figure1]
"The homogenous equation describes a hypothetical
situation where light passes by the Sun in a straight line without changing
direction
If b is the minimum distance from the photon to the center of the star
and r = r(φ) is the distance when the angle is φ (see figure 1), show that
$$\ {u}=\frac{\cos\phi}{b}$$ 
and use this to show that u then solves the homogenous equation:

$$\frac {d^2u}{d{\phi}^2}+{u}=0$$"

Source: http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT1001/h15/oblig2_eng.pdf
(the picture is originally from the link. Pressed Fn and Print Scrn while on the site then put it on paint for then to crop the figure out and save it)
A mandatory task.

I have tried this using CAH from soh cah toa: $${u}=\frac{b}{r}:{b}$$ 
Thus crossing out both b. For then to integrate on both sides, swapping r with r(φ): $$\int{u}{du}=\int{r\phi}{d\phi}$$ -> $${0.5}\int{u^2}{du}={o.5}\int{r\phi^2}{d\phi}$$
Beilivie this is wrong.

Comment: Plug this $u$ in the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluate
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2u}{\mathrm d\phi^2}+u=0\;\;\text{where}\;\;u=\frac{\cos(\phi)}{b}.$$
Substitute $u=\dfrac{\cos(\phi)}{b}$:
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d\phi^2}\frac{\cos(\phi)}{b}+\frac{\cos(\phi)}{b}=0;$$
carry the constant factor $\dfrac{1}{b}$ out of the differential sign:
$$\frac{1}{b}\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d\phi^2}\cos(\phi)+\frac{\cos(\phi)}{b}=0;$$
the second derivative of $\cos(\phi)$ with respect to $\phi$ is $-\cos(\phi)$:
$$-\frac{\cos(\phi)}{b}+\frac{\cos(\phi)}{b}=0;$$
simplify:
$$0=0;$$
the expression $0=0$ is true, write out the answer:
$$\therefore\top.$$

Comment: so the derivative of $${sin\phi}$$ is $${-cos\phi}$$?

Comment: @rufaelJ.O that is incorrect. The derivative of $\sin(\phi)$ with respect to $\phi$ is $\cos(\phi)$. If you are struggling to grasp why is the second derivative of $\cos(\phi)$ with respect to $\phi$ is $-\cos(\phi)$, please recall that the first derivative of $\cos(\phi)$ with respect to $\phi$ is $-\sin(\phi)$.

Comment: Do I have your consent to copy  off yor answer? And had your consent, I had copied from it before asking you for permission.

Comment: @rufaelJ.O sure. If I wasn't okay with that, I would not post my work here in the first place. I am not absolutely positive, but I think the license here permits you to do so without any notification and/or attribution whatsoever. Everyone is welcome to correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are given a function $u$ and asked to verify that is indeed a solution. This means you just need to calculate $\frac {d^2u}{d{\phi}^2}+{u}$ and show that it is $0$.